# How to display the user input entries for mad libs generator in one window, including the story in another window(using tkinter, code included)

Tags: python, tkinter

The user input entries are in the window (opnw1), what should be the code to display the whole story including the entries in the window (opnw1a), please give me an example code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("MAD LIBS STORY GENERATOR")

root.geometry("650x200")

root.configure(bg = "cyan")


w = tk.Label(root, text="WELCOME TO MAD LIBS STORY GENERATOR!" ,fg = "black", bg = "cyan", font = "Helvetica 20 bold italic")

w.pack()
   
photo1 = PhotoImage(file = r"E:\pen.png")

photoimage1 = photo1.subsample(3,3)


def opnw():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    
    top.title("CHOICES!!")
    
    top.geometry("650x200")
    
    top.configure(bg="cyan")

    s = tk.Label(top,text=" CHOOSE YOUR STORY CHOICE : ", fg="Black" , bg = "cyan" , font="Helvetica 20 bold italic")

    s.pack()

    def opnw1():
        
        top1 = Toplevel(top)
    
        top1.title("bE KIND")

        top1.geometry("400x500")

        top1.configure(bg="cyan")

        t = tk.Label(top1,text="FILL YOUR WORDS" , fg="dark blue" , bg="cyan" , font="helvetica 30 italic")

        t.pack()
        

        l1 = tk.Label(top1, text="  NOUN : " , fg="black" , bg="cyan" , font="helvetica 15 bold")

        l1.pack()
 
        e1 = tk.Entry(top1, bd=6)

        e1.pack()
        

        l2 = tk.Label(top1, text="  NOUN(PLURAL) : " , fg="black" , bg="cyan" , font="helvetica 15 bold")
           
        l2.pack()
        
        e2 = tk.Entry(top1, bd=6)

        e2.pack()

        
        l3 = tk.Label(top1, text="  NOUN : " , fg="black" , bg="cyan" , font="helvetica 15 bold")
           
        l3.pack()
        
        e3 = tk.Entry(top1, bd=6)

        e3.pack()
        

        l4 = tk.Label(top1, text="  PLACE : " , fg="black" , bg="cyan" , font="helvetica 15 bold")
           
        l4.pack()
        
        e4 = tk.Entry(top1, bd=6)

        e4.pack()
        

        l5 = tk.Label(top1, text="  ADJECTIVE : " , fg="black" , bg="cyan" , font="helvetica 15 bold")
           
        l5.pack()
        
        e5 = tk.Entry(top1, bd=6)

        e5.pack()
        

        l6 = tk.Label(top1, text="  NOUN : " , fg="black" , bg="cyan" , font="helvetica 15 bold")
           
        l6.pack()
        
        e6 = tk.Entry(top1, bd=6)

        e6.pack()

        
        def opwn1a():
            
            top3 = Toplevel(top1)
            
            top3.title("Completed story")
            
            top3.geometry("700x700")
            
            top3.configure(bg="cyan")

            def st(top3):
                l1=e1.get()
                l2=e2.get()
                l3=e3.get()
                l4=e4.get()
                l5=e5.get()
                l6=e6.get()

                story = "be kind to your"
                story += l1
                story +="-footed"
                story += l2
                story +="For a duck may ne somebody's"
                story += l3
                story += "Be kind to your"
                story += l2
                story += "in"
                story += l4
                story += "where the weather is always"
                story += l5
                story += "you may think that this is the"
                story += l6
                story += "Well It is."
            
            
                 
        d = tk.Button(top1, text="LET'S GO!!" , bd=7,fg="white" , bg="navy blue", command=lambda:[opwn1a,top3.st])

        d.pack()


    a = tk.Button(top, text="BE KIND" , bd=6 , font="helvetica" , compound = LEFT , command = opnw1)

    a.pack()




    def opnw2():
        top2 = Toplevel(top)

        top2.title("soooo")

        top2.geometry("700x300")

        top2.configure(bg="cyan")

        u = tk.Label(top2, text="fILL YOUR WORDS" , fg="dark blue" , bg="cyan" , font="helvetica 30 italic")

        u.pack()


    b = tk.Button(top, text="Sooooooo" , bd=6 , font="helvetica" , compound = RIGHT , command = opnw2)

    b.pack()
     

v = tk.Button(root, text = "Let's Create A Story!!", bd = 6 ,font = "helvetica", image = photoimage1 , compound = RIGHT , command=opnw)

v.pack()

frame = Frame(root)

frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="cyan",  width=105 , height=100 , highlightthickness=0)

canvas.pack()

photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="E:\lmf.png")


canvas.create_image(55, 47 , image=photoimage)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you not tried using `global`, there are two scopes with python `local` and `global`. Codes written in the main block(outside function) are defined in the global scope, means its available to use anywhere in the code. But variables defined inside a function is just available to use inside the function, because those are locally defined. To make a local variable global, just say `global var_name`.

Here is a simple example to understand this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def main():
    global e #making it available to global scope
    new = Toplevel()
    e = Entry(root)
    e.pack()

def take():
    print(e.get()) #printing it out in another function

main() #create a new window

b = Button(root,text='Click to print whats inside the entry',command=take)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Without `global e` python would throw an error that `e` is undefined.

Comment: If I'm not Wrong, I should try assigning a global variable in opnw1 and then should be using it in opnw1a?

Comment: @SHREYA It should work, give it a try. If you want to use the variable in a nested function, it doesnt need to be `global`. Which means in your case it should work without any `global`

Comment: I'll try that, but it's like I have to use def for combining the entries into a story, a nested definition under opnw1a, but when I try to define something like def st(top3): it shows attribute error.

Comment: @shreya Post the full error code in the question please.

Comment: Yes, I have posted it.

Comment: @Shreya Im sorry, i dont see any error in the Q? I mean to post the code of the attribute error you got in the Q

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Projects\INITIAL PLAN WITH TKINTER.py", line 145, in <lambda>
    d = tk.Button(top1, text="LET'S GO!!" , bd=7,fg="white" , bg="navy blue", command=lambda:[opwn1a,top3.st])
NameError: name 'top3' is not defined . This is what I'm getting when I click the Let's Go button

Comment: @Shreya What do you mean to do with `command=lambda:[opwn1a,top3.st]`, command is to trigger a function and `top3` is not a function, first of all. The code structure is hard to understand for me. Your using alot of nested function, just use `global` and try. It should get rid of the `NameError` but will give another error because `top3` is not a function

Comment: I will let you know , Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I go the desired output by just keeping the nested functions.,anyways thank you for helping me out!